# multiprocessing incorrectly returning an empty array

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, concurrency

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198612/how-do-i-run-video-detection-with-multiprocessing/71198728#71198728) post I asked for some help with multiprocessing as I was struggling to get a return variable and was suggested to check out `threading` instead.

I found [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU) looking for something on threading and it that explains that using `concurrent.futures` I can return a value, this sounds ideal as I need to return a `numpy.array`.

I've tried simply to run my `videoLoop` function with `concurrent.futures` to see what happens before going any further.

This code correctly returns a populated `np.array`. However, `cv.imshow` displays once and then closes despite the array returning correctly.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures
from PIL import ImageGrab

def videoLoop():
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(500, 50, 600, 60))
    img_np = np.array(img )
    DetectionWindow= cv.cvtColor(img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow("Video Loop", DetectionWindow)
    cv.waitKey(1)
    return DetectionWindow

while True:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        f1 = executor.submit(videoLoop)
```

I've tried to adapt the above to my actual code and instead I get an array of zeros.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures
import pygetwindow
from PIL import ImageGrab


def videoLoop():
    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Notepad')[0]
    x1 = window.left
    y1 = window.top
    height = window.height
    width = window.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    (width, height) = (haystack_img.width // 2, haystack_img.height // 2)
    haystack_img_resized = haystack_img.resize((width, height))
    crop = haystack_img_resized.crop((360,22,600,65))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(crop)
    haystack = cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow("Video Loop", haystack)
    cv.waitKey(1)
    return haystack

while True:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        f1 = executor.submit(videoLoop)
        print(f1.result())
```

What am I missing to return my actual array? and how can I ensure `cv.imshow` returns a video loop as expected.

Update re: comments

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import concurrent.futures
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pygetwindow

def videoLoop():

    window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Notepad')[0]
    x1 = window.left
    y1 = window.top
    height = window.height
    width = window.width
    x2 = x1 + width
    y2 = y1 + height
    haystack_img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x1, y1, x2, y2))
    haystack_img_np = np.array(haystack_img)
    DetectionWindow= cv.cvtColor(haystack_img_np, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #cv.imshow("Video Loop", DetectionWindow)
    #cv.waitKey(1)
    return DetectionWindow

while True:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        f1 = executor.submit(videoLoop)
        window = f1.result()
        cv.imshow("Video Loop", window)
        cv.waitKey(1)
        print(f1.result())
```

Comment: Can't help with anything but this has given me some ideas of where to take my own work.

Comment: please present a [mre].

Comment: I thought it was, updated & added the imports and removed the break in the code.

Comment: Ok significantly re did things @ChristophRackwitz

Comment: yeah all of that is a bad idea. -- all the GUI stuff (imshow, waitkey) needs to stay in the main thread, i.e. not go in any threads that are "created". -- and no, I can't reproduce the issue. if I remove all the needless GUI stuff from the `videoLoop` task target, I can see the arrays correspond to what's on my screen.

Comment: I've changed things around a little, oddly when notepad is on a different monitor the arrays return zero but when on the same monitor as my IDE they populate. The code I've just updated in the OP executes once and then stops, any idea why? I think I've got the opposite of what you've just said (imshow, waitkey) in the created thread? assuming `concurrent.futures` is creating a `videoLoop` thread. When I swap things around and uncomment imshow, waitkey in the videoLoop function imshow appears once then vanishes.

Comment: I see this stopping too. I am not in the mood to debug this, but you can. just run it in the python debugger and single-step it. -- again, do not put the OpenCV GUI stuff into any threads.

Comment: and maybe skip the thread stuff entirely. what you do makes it totally pointless. you engage the pool and then still wait for the result. pointless. don't use threads here. that's not a suggestion or opinion. what you do here with the pool _is pointless_. it would _only_ make sense if you did any other work between submission and requiring the result from the returned Future.

Comment: The tread stuff is just a POC, for now, to make sure I can run a video loop like this and get a return value out of it, I realise it doesn't actually seem needed in this example. Oddly when I single-step it, it loops once, and then stops on `window = f1.result` and nothing else happens, I can't single-step any further and the debugger is blank. Any ideas?